# Can't establish internet connection on the Beaglebone Black running on Big Sur (OSX)

Tags: linux, macos, networking, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack

I am having trouble setting up an internet to be shared on Beaglebone (BB) through the host (Mac running Big Sur OS).

When I do `ifconfig` on BB, I see two USB interfaces showing up (usb0, usb1) with designated IP addresses but I can't seem to ping to my host machine for instance to verify the internet connection. It says `From 192.168.7.2 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable`

According to this [link](https://beagleboard.org/latest-images):

> With the latest images, it should no longer be necessary to install drivers for your operating system to give you network-over-USB access to your Beagle. In case you are running an older image, an older operating system or need additional drivers for serial access to older boards, links to the old drivers are below.

```
usb0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.7.2  netmask 255.255.255.252  broadcast 192.168.7.3
        inet6 fe80::e1c:57ff:fe00:c2c0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 0c:1c:57:00:c2:c0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

usb1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.6.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.6.255
        ether 0c:1c:57:00:c2:c4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

- I did download the latest image but for further verification, how do you verify the image being run i.e version or something that tells whether this matches the image version 10.3 as stated on the website?
- On the host, following is the relevant interface for the USB. For the pings to go through, the netmask needs to be matched with that of the `usb0`?

```
en7: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=404<VLAN_MTU,CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 0c:1c:57:00:c2:c3 
    inet6 fe80::d1:b3cb:50eb:72e1%en7 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x14 
    inet 192.168.7.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.6.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect (none)
    status: inactive
```

- In the [Network Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soifD.png) of the host, I see it says `Either the cable for BeagleBoneBlack is not plugged in or the device at the other end is not responding.` That's weird because in the `ifconfig` output on the host, I do see `en7` showing up which is referring to the USB connection to the BeagleBone

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not questions about using or setting up Linux or networking. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Answer (score 0):

```
uname -a
```

This shows your kernel

```
cat /etc/dogtag
```

This shows your image

Are you using an Ethernet cable or are you trying to use a USB dongle for Wifi? If you are using Ethernet, it should be plug and play but you will need to use Chrome or Firefox.

I am not sure about the Big Sur OS but you can try beaglebone.local or 192.168.6.2 instead. This may prove useful when using ssh.

also...try this:

```
use a COM port or if there is no COM ports on Big Sur OS, get a 
USB to TTL converter cable and get onto the board via serial...
```

This way, you can find your IP Address by `ip addr`.

Look for eth0 on the BBB and not usb(x).

Comment: right on. `Debian Buster IoT Grove Kit Image 2020-04-06` is my image which seems correct/latest. For now, I'm using using a USB cable to connect the beaglebone to my host machine, and as mentioned, I'm also seeing a USB interface on the host `(en7)`, but can't seem to share the internet on beaglebone. Also what are you referring to by 192.168.6.2? this is an IP of `usb1` interface on beaglebone

Comment: Hello...do you need the Grove Kit Image for anything outside of connecting to the www? I am asking b/c for regular stuff for the BBB, I choose the correct image: https://beagleboard.org/latest-images <<< It is the second one down in blue lettering.

Comment: Just need access to its linux shell, and internet. I have access to the shell but no the internet. Isn't that what Grove image is for? Actually there are no details specified there

Comment: so do you think the error I'm seeing in network settings regarding how cable is unplugged the culprit? I'm just not sure how come I'm seeing a USB interface on the host then if beaglebone isn't recognized. Or that's referring to a UART port?

Comment: Hello...if you are not using the BBGW or BBG (beaglebone Green), I suggest using another image.

Comment: mind elaborating? which image are you referring to? and I already mentioned I'm using beaglebone black

Comment: Hello...the second one down w/ the blue lettering on the /latest-images page on beagleboard.org.